# Error with uploading Asset Files: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: assets, error-message, upload

In my local MAMP site I'm not able to upload any files.

**Gives me this error in Chrome:**

http://nobel.craft.dev:8888/index.php?p=admin/actions/assets/uploadFile net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

**This error in Safari**

"Failed to load a resource: The network connection was lost."

**Things I did**

- I've checked the asset folder path
- makes sure folder is writable
- nothing strange in the craft.log
- delete cache in admin
- download new version of craft and replaced the app folder

Comment: Have you tried another browser (I'm assuming you're using chrome and the first page of google results for ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE are all chrome issues)?

Comment: Yes. Tried Safari.

[Error] "Failed to load a resource: The network connection was lost." (index.php, line 0)

Answer (score 2):

That usually means "something fatal happened" when trying to upload the file.  The usual culprits are the php.ini `max_execution_time` and `memory_limit` settings, but if it's happening for small files too, something else could be going on.

Have also seen it happen when you're uploading an image in a format your underlying image processing library doesn't support.  i.e. your server has [GD](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) installed, but you're trying to upload a 32-bit PNG.  Or you're running an older version of GD or [Imagick](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) that has a bug you're hitting.

Check if you have a `craft/storage/runtime/logs/phperrors.log` file.  Any PHP fatal errors will be logged there.  If not, then check the Apache error logs to see if it's an Apache problem.