# Error uploading images on admin panel ( Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE )

Tags: image, admin, debugging

I have a problem uploading images on the CP. Small images success, but one with a 2Mb site fails with the error below.

File was renamed to only ASCII chars, but problem still occures.

[image]
PHP settings:

```
memory_limit    128M
upload_max_filesize 64M
```

Craft version: 2.6.2791

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error with uploading Asset Files: net::ERR\_EMPTY\_RESPONSE](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/5309/error-with-uploading-asset-files-neterr-empty-response)

Comment: Unfortunately no, all my settings are decently high and I found no logs of this error.

Comment: Try bumping memory to 256M? Running GD or Imagick and what version?

Comment: memory_limit is now 256M, still the same error. I turned on DevMode and no errors were logged, not even in PHP logs in /var/logs...

GD Support enabled
GD Version 2.1.1-dev

I can't refresh imagemagick, apt-get dies with segmentation fault :)

Comment: "utils/serverinfo" says ImageMagick passed with warnings, however I can't see those warnings.